# How to denote the domain of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have the integral $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx$ and instead of writing both the limits I want to write $\int_{\Omega} f(x) \,dx$, where is $\Omega$ is the domain of integration.

**My question:**

Should I use $\in$ or $=$ for $\Omega$? I.e. is it correct to write

\begin{align}
\int_\Omega f(x) \,dx, \quad \Omega \in [a,b] \tag 1  
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega f(x) \,dx, \quad \Omega =[a,b] \tag 2
\end{align}
?

Comment: The second is correct. $ \Omega $ is the set, not the variable ($ x \in \Omega$).

Comment: You may write $\int_{[a,b]} f(x)\>dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the set of integration $\Omega $ is a set (realy) so the second is correct.